# Prove $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{14}$ is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra

I dont know how to work out what $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{14}$ is. It says in the answers $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{14}$
 is the set of $1,3,5,9,11,13$ but I dont understand how they got that. I know what a unit group is but I cant figure out how 3 can be in the group when $\frac{1}{3}$ isnt in $Z$ or $Z_{14}$

Comment: $3\times 5\equiv 1 \pmod {14}$, so $3$ has an inverse $\pmod {14}$.

Comment: $\gcd(3,14)=1$ so $3\in\Bbb Z_{14}^\times$.

Comment: oh i see, I looked at the definition of unit groups with only inverses as i defined above

Answer (score 1):

You are been asked a generator of Z14* , as  Z14* has 6 elements, the order of any subgroup (and so the order of the group generated by any element) is 1,2,3 or 6 , (divisor of 6). Now you just have to find one element of order 6, 1 has order 1, 3^1=3 mod 14 , 3^2=9 mod 14, 3^3 =27=13 mod 14 ,since its order is bigger than 3 you now know its order has to be 6, and then 3 is a generator. But you may what to give all the elements as a power of 3 , so 3^4 =11 mod 14, 3^5=5 mod 14 and finally 3^6 = 1 mod 14.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\phi(14)=6$, the group of units of $\Bbb{Z}/14\Bbb{Z}$ has $6$ elements and is abelian. Hence it must be cyclic, i.e., isomorphic to $C_6$, because $S_3$ is non-abelian. So the question from the title is answered.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorant question, how do we know $\phi(n)$ is the number of elements in the units group of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$? I'm asking if you can can explain how do you prove this?

Comment: This is the definition of $\phi(n)$. The number of integers $1\le k\le n$ coprime to $n$. So the number of invertible elements in $\Bbb{Z}/n$.

Comment: Oh, okay, I get it. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

By the *Chinese remainder theorem*, we have a ring isomorphism:
\begin{align}
&&\mathbf Z/14\mathbf Z&\simeq \mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z\times \mathbf Z/7\mathbf Z,\\[1ex]
&\mbox{whence a  group }\rlap{ isomorphism:} && &&\hspace8em\\[1ex]
&&\bigl(\mathbf Z/14\mathbf Z\bigr)^{\!\times}&\simeq \bigl(\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z\bigr)^{\!\times}\times \bigl(\mathbf Z/7\mathbf Z\bigr)^{\!\times}\simeq\{1\}\times \mathbf Z/6\mathbf Z \simeq \mathbf Z/6\mathbf Z.
\end{align}
Remember $\mathbf Z/7\mathbf Z$ is a field with $7$ elements, and the group of units of a finite field is cyclic.

Answer (score 0):

The group contains the positive integers up to 14 that are relatively prime to 14, which means that they can't share any divisors with 14.  Thus anything with a 2 or 7 for a divisor needs to be removed.  This leaves you with the {1,3,5,9,11,13} that you have listed above.

Don't think of inverses in the same way as reciprocals in the set of fractions.  You are correct that 1/3 doesn't exist, yet 3*5 is equal to 1.  This means 5 plays the same role here as 1/3 does in the set of fractions. They both take 3 back to one when you multiply.